# $_GET variable showing in one PHP file but not in another PHP file

Tags: javascript, php, get

This is the problem:

**(1) I have one PHP file that connects to a databse.**

```
<?php
function db_connect() {

        // Define connection as a static variable, to avoid connecting more than once 
    static $connection;

        // Try and connect to the database, if a connection has not been established yet
    if(!isset($connection)) {
             // Load configuration as an array. Use the actual location of your configuration file
        $config = parse_ini_file('/home/abfopcre/private/config.ini'); 
        $connection = mysqli_connect($config['servername'],$config['username'],$config['password'],$config['dbname']);
    }

        // If connection was not successful, handle the error
    if($connection === false) {
            // Handle error - notify administrator, log to a file, show an error screen, etc.
        return mysqli_connect_error(); 
    }
    return $connection;
}

// Connect to the database
$connection = db_connect();

if (isset($_GET['uid'])) { 
    $uid=$_GET['uid'];
}
echo $uid;
?>
```

Now the important part is only the variable $uid. When I type in dbconnect.php?uid=123 for example, it correctly echoes "123".

**(2) I have another PHP file called index.php in which I pass on the variable "uid" to the php script using XMLHttpRequest in JavaScript:**

```
...
if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }

      else {
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }

        var url = "../dbconnect.php?uid=" + user.uid;

        xmlhttp.open("GET", url, false);
        xmlhttp.send();
...
```

**(3) I included a reference in index.php to link to dbconnect.php**

```
<?php
                        include("../dbconnect.php");
?>
```

Now, since there's an echo in dbconnect.php, the variable should also be echoed in index.php but it's empty. This confuses me since in the console I see that the XMLHttpRequest went through successfully. What can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: This may seem silly but have you tried echoing anything else on index.php? You may want to change `echo $uid;` to `echo "UID: " + uid;` to at least verify it's just the $_GET value not displaying.

Comment: I did and everything except the $_GET value is displaying.

Comment: Not sure if you are still looking at this but in the send use this
var url = "../dbconnect.php";
 xmlhttp.open("GET", url, false);
xmlhttp.send("uid=" + user.uid);

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately not working either.

Comment: Yes, it's even showing in the JavaScript console log.

Comment: Can you post the console log and the network information because I dont see an issue... because the last issue I see can be: "../dbconnect.php" and its not looking in the correct directory.